# Javascript Regex Match pattern that matches words and numbers with spaces and commas

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a list of strings and I want to perform a on-the-fly shortlisting on them. I am able to do a raw match that is case-insensitve, however I need further than that. I need to make sure that when a user enters a number without commas and spaces I need to match it with my input list. I have reduced my problem set to this JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jbragadeesh/hy2e2dkL/2/

HTML

```
<input type='text' id='textbox'></input>
<ul>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
    <li>cat</li>
    <li>AB 2, 343, 1223,1</li>
    <li>Happy Docking 1 2 4</li>
    <li>88898889</li>
    <li>12abcd34</li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$('#textbox').on('keyup', function(){
    keyword = $('#textbox').val();
    match_pattern = new RegExp(keyword, 'gi');
    $( "li" ).each(function() {
      element = $(this);
        if(element.text().search(match_pattern) != -1){
            element.show();
        } else{
            element.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Now, when I type `234312231`, the item `AB 2, 343, 1223,1` should match, when input is `124` the `Happy Docking 1 2 4` should match. However when I type `1234` nothing should match (not even the last one `12abcd34` as there are text in-between). Can someone please suggest me a regular expression for that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `replace` method to get rid of `,` and spaces when looking for a match (should be applied to both `match_pattern` and `element.text()`):

```
match_pattern = new RegExp(keyword.replace(/[ ,]/g, ''), 'gi');
if(element.text().replace(/[ ,]/g, '').search(match_pattern) != -1){
```

See [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/768s7rL6/1/)

Comment: But I cannot search "Happy Docking" anymore. Its not matching. Should I add another condition ?

Comment: Please check the update. I also noticed it right after I found out I can't get the `AB 2, 343, 1223,1` value by typing `2,343`. It should be working now.